# Is there any convinient way to periodically check thread state?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I need to cleanup every running threads in case the main thread is finished. I put running thread in the `List<Thread>` collection immediately after it has been started.
My "wheel" approach is:

```
static void CheckThreadIsAliveJob(object thread)
{
    while (((Thread)thread).IsAlive)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    // DO staff
}
```

I think my approach is very expensive for huge amount of threads, because I need to start new thread with `CheckThreadIsAliveJob` body for every of them.

Any ideas?

I rewrited the code above, but this still looks agly:

```
    static void RemoveFinishedThreadsJob(object threadList)
    {
        foreach (var thread in (IList<Thread>)threadList)
        {
            if (!thread.IsAlive)
                lock (threadList)
                {
                    ((IList<Thread>) threadList).Remove(thread);
                }

        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

I've implemented Dispose method of IDisposable interface in my class:

```
        public void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (var thread in _runningThreads)
            {
                if (thread.IsAlive)
                    thread.Abort();
                if (_removeFinishedThreads.IsAlive)
                    _removeFinishedThreads.Abort();
            }
        }
```

Now, when application is closing and GC is collecting garbage, all running threads are manually aborting.

Comment: You are re-implementing the Thread.IsBackground property.  Just set it to *true*.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just looping around waiting for the thread to exit. If that's the case then just use [Thread.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to wait for it to exit.

Also, never use `Thread.About` as it can leave your program is a bad state. Instead communicate to the thread that it should shut down and the wait for the thread to exit by a call to `Join`.

Comment: "Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates." So, how to be for large amount of threads?

Comment: It won't matter. You're busy spinning in your `RemoveFinishedThreadJobs` just waiting for everything to finish. This is wasting that CPU, and you're effectively blocking. Just wait for the thread to exit instead rather than polling it.

Comment: Could you provide some example? I'm not getting, how blocking Join may help me to collect running threads to cleanup them. Thread may never return, so I need to cleanup it in case my app is closing. Also, I'm not busy, cause spinning is in the separate thread, also cleaned up, when app is closing.

Comment: You should write your threads in such a way that they will return when you want to do something like a shutdown. Thread.About is never the right way to terminate a thread.

Comment: Of course, you are right, I remember about resources, that might be lost in case of abrupt thread termination. Now I'm thinking of some signal pattern to let each thread know about shutdown intention.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the other threads to finish when you terminate your main thread, just set their `Thread.IsBackground=true`
and they will automatically be terminated as well.

Comment: Thank you, this is a part of solution. It would be greate to release resources catched by the thread.

Comment: No worries.
Yes, that is a problem. For possible solutions, check this link:
[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527570-03-19.aspx)
          
Especially focus on the part starting with:
_"When a background thread terminates in this manner, any finally blocks are circumvented. This is a problem if your program employs finally blocks (or the using keyword) to perform cleanup work such as releasing resources or deleting temporary files. To avoid this, you can explicitly wait out such background threads upon exiting an application."_